# How to get count for each number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table like that

```
Name  Value
test  1
test  1
test  2
test  3
```

how to get something like this?

```
Name 1  2  3
test 2  1  1
```

Comment: So you want to PIVOT the data? (hint hint...)

Comment: SQL questions about turning rows into column names should be banned from SO.

Comment: He is asking about counting, not pivoting the data...It is just a bit off a confusing example.

Comment: @NickA Aggregating and pivoting actually.

Comment: You are right, when I thought more about it, then i figured that out. I was about to edit my comment when you commented. :)

Comment: no, i need to get count of each value in a new column name something like that

Comment: @HassanAbdallah Yes, that is what pivoting is.

Comment: And if you don't know how many columns there are going to be, then you need to do a `dynamic pivot`.

Comment: @DavidG thanks the below comment with code is working for me not like you said using pivot :)

Comment: @HassanAbdallah That query is still a pivot, it's just not dynamic.

Comment: @DavidG than's why i asked here to get the best answer. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

```
select 
  name,
  sum(IIF(Value=1, 1,0)) as c1,
  sum(IIF(Value=2, 1,0)) as c2,
  sum(IIF(Value=3, 1,0)) as c2
from t
group by name
```

Comment: What is there is a value 4 in the table?

Comment: Can you update this answer for when there are 167,000 different values to work with?

Comment: then I prefer to use pivot which seems it is not the case here

Comment: This is still a pivot, why is everyone so reluctant to call this what it is?

Comment: @Simonare And asking for accepts is considered bad form around here too...

Comment: @DavidG I am not arguing about the meaning of PIVOT. I am just sayıng that IF the columns will me moree I prefer to use `PIVOT` function. I think you are overthinking

Comment: @DavidG then you don't do it. It is up to you. AFAIK it is not restricted to do so. I am not asking for favor right? :)